# Exporting search results to Excel in Asp.Net MVC has slowed down the whole application

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, excel

I am building a sample mvc application. I am trying to export search results to excel. I stored my search results in a session and export that session list to excel. It was working fine when I was playing around with small database that has only 2000 rows. Now I have around 300K rows in my database. Searching the results and exporting to excel still working fine. But my application slowed down drastically.

When I comment out below code my application runs fine again, as soon as I uncomment it will slowed down.

```
  //Session["SearchResults"] = aPPET.ToList<APPET>();
```

What would be the best way to do it when there is large database?

I read post about closedxml, but not really sure how to implement it. Do I need to create store procedure if I go that route? Or is there any better way.

Please suggests.

Below is my controller codes:

```
public class APPET1Controller : Controller
{
   private APContext db = new APContext();

// GET: APPET1
public ActionResult Index(string search, string cagecode, string sortBy, 
                          int? page, string docNumber, string remark, string status)
{
    APPETViewModel viewModel = new APPETViewModel();

    var aPPET1 = db.APPET1.Include(t =>T.APPETMedia)
                                .Include(t => t.Status)
                                .Include(t => t.APPETCCode)
                                .Include(t => t.APPETDType);
             ............some more codes..............

    DateTime searchDate;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        bool isDateSearch = DateTime.TryParse(search, out searchDate);
        if (isDateSearch)
        {
            aPPET1 = aPPET1.Where(s => s.Date_Received == searchDate);
        }

        else
        {
            aPPET1 = aPPET1.Where(t.Doc_Number.Contains(search)
                    || t.Status.Status1.Contains(search)
                    || t.Remark.Contains(search)
                    || t.CCode.Contains(search));
         ..............some more codes..............
           viewModel.Search = search;
        }

    }

    var stats = db.Status.Select(s => s.Status1);
    viewModel.Statuses = new SelectList(stats);
    {

      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
      {
        aPPET1 = aPPET1.Where(t => t.Status.Status1.Contains(status));
      }
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(docNumber))
    {   
        aPPET1 = aPPET1.Where(t => t.Doc_Number.Contains(docNumber));
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(remark))
    {
        aPPET1 = aPPET1.Where(t => t.Remark.Contains(remark));
    }
 ............some more codes.........

    Session["SearchResults"] = aPPET.ToList<APPET>();
    return View(viewModel);

}
```

Comment: We normally let those long running jobs run at background jobs.

Comment: Don't store the search results in the session--that will use quite a bit of memory. When exporting, run the search query again and write the results directly to the output stream as CSV or generate an XLSX package on the server and stream it to the client.

Comment: What Dan said above - don't store the results in the session - this will persist beyond the time your download has finished, and use up lots of memory for no reason. If several users do this at once, it'll soon eat up lots of server memory and degrade performance. Sessions can persist for a long time, depending on usage and your app settings, and each set of results will stay in memory until that session expires. There's really no need to store this in the session as far as I can see.

Comment: If you desperately don't want to run the search query a second time in order for the export to work, then consider storing the results in a database table and giving the result set an ID (associated with the user, if necessary for security), which you pass to the client along with the results. Then they can pass this ID back when requesting the export and it can just fetch the results from the table instantly. Have a background task which clears out the table at regular intervals. If the user comes to export and their ID has expired, just re-run the search.

Comment: @ADyson, can you give me a simple example on how to store search result in database please. Does entity framework support temp table?